# Appending an image that fits set dimensions using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to append images to a element with a specified height and width. The image itself may be bigger or smaller than that height and width and I want to adjust the image to fit the size rather than repeating or showing only part of the image.

Javascript:

I got the URL of the image as well as its height and width, then I tried creating the element and setting its properties here.

```
     var listingEntry = document.createElement("img");
     listingEntry.setAttribute("height", height);
     listingEntry.setAttribute("width", width);
     listingEntry.className = "classTitle";
     listingEntry.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSourceUrl + ")";
```

Then I got the element from the DOM by Id and appended it:

```
     var gridArticle = document.getElementById("gridArticle");
     gridArticle.appendChild(listingEntry);
```

And my CSS:

```
article .tile {

display: inline-block;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;

font-size: 3em;
font-weight: 700;

padding: 0 6px;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;

}

article img {

}
```

I tried:

```
article img {
   max-height: 100% 
   max-width: 100%
}
```

But then the images stopped showing up all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this in two different ways:

1) Create a div and set a background image:

```
var listingEntry = document.createElement("div");
listingEntry.setAttribute("height", height);
listingEntry.setAttribute("width", width);
listingEntry.className = "classTitle";
listingEntry.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSourceUrl + ")";
```

or 2) Create an img and set a src that points to the url:

```
var listingEntry = document.createElement("img");
listingEntry.setAttribute("height", height);
listingEntry.setAttribute("width", width);
listingEntry.className = "classTitle";
listingEntry.src = imageSourceUrl;
```

NOTE: I would go with the second approach. Also try to avoid setting a background image to an img element, since the element's content tend to mask the background.

Comment: I am currently using way number 1 and it works fine. Do you know what properties I have to adjust so that the images will scale to fit whatever size dimension I specify so that it does not repeat the image or only show a portion?

Comment: try the following:
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the source of your image:

```
var listingEntry = document.createElement("img");
listingEntry.setAttribute("height", height);
listingEntry.setAttribute("width", width);
listingEntry.className = "classTitle";
```

<strike>`listingEntry.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSourceUrl + ")";`</strike>

```
listingEntry.src = imageSourceUrl;
```